# HTML5 localStorage replace data to already existing key

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have the following [localStorage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) key:

```
localStorage.setItem(1, "<div id='MyId'>value 1</div><div id='NewId'>other value</div>");
```

Is it possible to replace, change only the second id, make the:

```
<div id='MyId'>value 1</div><div id='NewId'>other value</div>
```

turn into

```
<div id='MyId'>value 1</div><div id='NewId'>replaced value</div>
```

I do not want to delete this key and create a new one, just replace a part of it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Taken from [Dive into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/storage.html#methods):

> Calling setItem() with a named key
>   that already exists will silently
>   overwrite the previous value.

So read the value with getItem() [if needed], do your replace, set the new value with setItem().